# Rails where based on association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, associations, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to query items based on an association but getting a bit confused with how to phrase the date part of my query.  The dates are stored in text format like "2018-12-25".

```
year = params[:ridden_in]
@items = Item.joins(:cycle).where(cycles: { (:date.to_date).year: year })
```

Anyone able to help out where i'm going wrong?

Comment: @muistooshort Changing the schema for that is on my to do list but can't do it right now.  Just need to get this working for the time being then will tweak that in the next few weeks.  I'm using PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use SQL functions. You could try to hide the SQL behind AREL but that very quickly becomes an incomprehensible mess.

One way would be straight string manipulation:

```
Item.joins(:cycle).where('substring(cycles."date" from 1 for 4) = ?', year)
```

or slightly more future-proof since your date will eventually become a real date:

```
Item.joins(:cycle).where('extract(year from cycles."date"::date) = ?', year)
Item.joins(:cycle).where('extract(year from cast(cycles."date" as date)) = ?', year)
```

Both of those assume that your `date` columns really do follow the ISO8601 date format.

If you're doing this a lot then you could add a partial index on `cycles.date` (i.e. index the result of whichever function you end up using).

Comment: I've just been trying these out but unfortunatley can't get any of them to work.  How would it be achieved if I change the field to a real date field?

Comment: What specifically does "can't get any of them to work" mean?